# What is Venom in Batman?

Tags: comics, dc, batman

I gather Venom's first appearance in Batman was in Batman: Legends of the Fall, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_%28DC_Comics%29#Venom).  I guess it's meant to be a steroids analogy.  Is the formulation of Venom revealed anywhere?  Was Bane using Venom from the very first time he appeared in the comics?

Comment: just in the morning i reeded an article about venom origins  the comics sadly it is in spanish and i reeded in flipboard :(, however the first apparence of bane it is in the jail he grown and learn in there, the venom formula was a DC formula for the super soldier

Comment: Check out the first appearance of Bane. It's a long story arc called *Batman: Vengeance of Bane*. There is also a scene in the *No Man's Land* story arc that explains Bane a bit.

Comment: I got you covered below. Enjoy.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As far as I know Venom is considered to be more than just steroids. It also contains stuff making the victim sensible for commands from assumed superiors, probably disabling other instincts like self-preservation, conscious thoughts, etc.

To be honest, I've never read the comics mentioned in the Wikipedia entry, but I think Batman & Robin (1997) depicted his creation quite accurate and believable: He's not a self-motivated vilain or anything. He's essentially a victim of experiments (Venom), which modify his body and mind so he becomes the "perfect" soldier (I wouldn't count the attachments such as hoses perfect, cause they're obviously his weak points): be almost invulnerable, obey commands without doubt, etc.

Also, like with almost any comic super drug or special thingy: I don't think the formula is revealed anywhere, nor are there any specific details on what "Venom" actually is. It might sound dumb, but there'd clearly be enough wicked minds in the real world, actually trying to create their own Venom. If you've ever seen MacGuyver, they used to name some details on the things he uses to create, e.g. some explosives, but the specifics are never revealed to protect the audience (and the producers' pockets from law suits). Even if it's fictive, someone WILL try it.

Comment: I find it disappointing that this is the selected answer - it's completely inaccurate - as was the portrayal of Bane in "Batman & Robin". Bane was a highly intelligent and self-motivated villain long before he ever encountered Venom. The drug itself was a poor attempt at a super-soldier serum that was being tested on convicts. The comics version of Bane was one of the few villains who could match Batman on both the mental AND physical level.

Comment: This is an absolutely atrocious answer, and may god have mercy on anyone who uses *Batman and Robin* as reference for **any** answer.

Comment: Yeah, well, sorry, but I can't even delete it while it's accepted. :P

Comment: A new standard for terrible answers.

Comment: The treatment of Bane in that despicable move is perhaps the greatest crime in a film that also cast the Last Action Governator as Mr. Freeze.

Answer (score 15):

#### Canonically, [Venom](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Venom) was an attempt to reverse engineer the super-strength, speed and stamina of another more well known metahuman-enhancement agent known as [Miraclo](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Miraclo), known for giving the [Golden Age Hourman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Hourman_(Rex_Tyler)), his abilities. Miraclo made it's first appearance in comics in Adventure Comics #48 (March, 1940). Venom is a potently addictive strength-enhancing super-steroid, in a fashion similar to the chemical compound it was based on.

> Miraclo was short for "miraculous vitamin". Concentrated doses of that "vitamin" gave a strength and vigor to test mice several times that of normal. The human body could only process the Miraclo for an hour at a time, whereafter the subject was weakened and returned to human strength levels.

- Created by chemist, Rex Tyler, the Golden Age Hourman could use Miraclo for an hour, giving him greatly enhanced strength, speed and durability. Able to run 50 miles an hour, jump to the top of a ten story building, and able to lift and throw a period vehicle twenty-five to thirty feet. (Granted, by today's metahuman standards, these are modest feats, but by Golden Age standards, for an hour, Hourman was tough!)
- Unfortunately, Miraclo had terrible side-effects, eventually weakening Tyler's heart and putting a strain on his body due to impurities in its formula. He would later attempt to refine it and coupled it with genetic engineering in the future.
- **According to JSA Classified #17 (November 2006)**, Venom is based on the Miraclo formula developed at Bannerman Pharmaceuticals, the drug company formerly owned by Rex Tyler, the original Hourman.

[image]

- The first appearance of the drug was a five-part story arc, Batman: Venom, in the Batman anthology series, Legends of the Dark Knight, issues 16-20. Batman became addicted to the drug while searching for a way to surpass his limitations.
- Later, it resurfaced as the power source for Bane, who used it to overpower and cripple Batman in the Knightfall story arc. A variant of the original Venom is used by President Lex Luthor in the first "Superman/Batman" story arc.

#### Bane

Bane was technically a bad-ass even before he became a user of Venom. Raised in a prison environment, he trained his body to the peak of human ability, killing 30 prisoners in the famed and dangerous Santa Prisca prison in Cuba.

[image]

Bane was chosen for the experiment and survived the toxic effects of the first test of the Venom drug (though he faked his death to escape prison.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 - a much better answer than my own. The images make a huge difference, plus I completely forgot about the Hourman connection.

Comment: Great answer, should be the accepted one

Answer (score 4):

Although similar in effect to a "super-steroid", the drug known as Venom was actually a failed attempt to create a super-soldier serum. The exact formulation is never shown in the comics, but the end result is extreme enhancement of the subject's musculature, resulting in vastly-increased strength, durability, and endurance.

At the time of Bane's initial appearance in the "Knightfall" arc, Bane was already using Venom to enhance his already-muscular physique. As we see in his origin story, he was a convict who grew up in the Pena Dura prison of the small Central American country Santa Prisca. Bane was a highly-intelligent & self-motivated individual, training himself over the years much as Bruce Wayne did and eventually becoming the undisputed "King" of Pena Dura. When the warden of the prison made a deal with an unknown party to test out their new Venom drug, it allowed the prison a convenient way to get rid of Bane. To their great surprise, however, Bane not only survived the experiment, he grew much more powerful and was able to escape.

Bane's desire to defeat Batman stems from a compulsion to prove his own superiority. Even without the Venom, Bane is one of the few foes who can match Batman on an intellectual level. With the Venom enhancing his strength, speed, and endurance, he can also overcome Batman on a physical level. Contrary to his portrayal in the poorly-received "Batman & Robin" film, Bane has never been considered a mere thug or henchman.

Answer (score 3):

The introduction of the Venom concept to the Batman mythos was in the "Venom" story arc in Legends of the Dark Knight 16-20 by Dennis O'Neil. It was collected shortly after publication, and reprinted early in 2012 so should be pretty easy to find.